# ApplyChanges not working from Toolpart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development

I've tried every solution, and searched every part of the internet, and yet, I do not seem to understand why my properties aren't saved. I've attacked the code. And maybe someone can help me out here:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages;

namespace Hein.SPF.Development.WebParts.SiteInfoWebPart
{

    public class SiteInfoWebPart : Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart
    {
        // Visual Studio might automatically update this path when you change the Visual Web Part project item.
        private const string _ascxPath = @"~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/Hein.SPF.Development.WebParts/SiteInfoWebPart/SiteInfoWebPartUserControl.ascx";

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            base.CreateChildControls();
            SiteInfoWebPartUserControl control = Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath) as SiteInfoWebPartUserControl;
            control.ItemId = this.ItemId;
            control.ListName = this.ListName;
            Controls.Add(control);
        }


        public override ToolPart[] GetToolParts()
        {
            ToolPart[] allToolParts = new ToolPart[3];

            try
            {

                    WebPartToolPart standardToolParts = new WebPartToolPart();
                    CustomPropertyToolPart customToolParts = new CustomPropertyToolPart();                    
                    allToolParts[0] = standardToolParts;
                    allToolParts[1] = customToolParts;
                    allToolParts[2] = new Hein.SPF.Development.Library.SiteInfoToolPart();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            return allToolParts;
        }




        [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
        [WebBrowsable(true)]
        [Category("Custom")]
        [WebDisplayName("Configuration List Name")]
        [Description("Configuration List Name")]
        [DefaultValue("Service Info")]
        public string ListName
        {
            get { return _ListName ; }
            set { _ListName = value; }
        }

        string _ListName;
        [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
        [WebBrowsable(true)]
        [Category("Custom")]
        [WebDisplayName("Configuration List Item")]
        [Description("Configuration List Item")]
        public string ItemId
        {
            get { return _ItemId; }
            set { _ItemId = value; }
        }

        string _ItemId;

        public void ApplyChanges()
        { 

        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using Hein.SPF.Development.WebParts.SiteInfoWebPart;
using ETTU.SPEC.Library.Logging;

namespace Hein.SPF.Development.Library
{
    class SiteInfoToolPart : Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ToolPart
    {
        #region Controls Declaration

        DropDownList ddlAllLists;
        DropDownList ddlItems;
        Panel toolPartPanel;
        SiteInfoWebPart siteInfoWp = null;

        #endregion


        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        ///
        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            try
            {
                siteInfoWp = (SiteInfoWebPart)ParentToolPane.SelectedWebPart;

                //SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                //{
                    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
                    {
                        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                        {

                            #region Creating instances of Toolpart Controls

                            toolPartPanel = new Panel();
                            toolPartPanel.GroupingText = "List Configuration";
                            //UpdatePanel updatePanel = new UpdatePanel();

                            ddlAllLists = new DropDownList();
                            ddlAllLists.ID = "ddlAllLists";
                            ddlAllLists.AutoPostBack = true;
                            ddlAllLists.Width = Unit.Pixel(200);
                            ddlAllLists.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddlAllLists_SelectedIndexChanged);

                            ddlItems = new DropDownList();
                            ddlItems.ID = "ddlItems";
                            ddlItems.AutoPostBack = true;
                            ddlItems.Width = Unit.Pixel(200);

                            #endregion

                            populateToolPartControls();

                            #region Adding all control to toolpart stack


                            toolPartPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Select List"));
                            toolPartPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</br>"));
                            toolPartPanel.Controls.Add(ddlAllLists);


                            toolPartPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</br>"));
                            toolPartPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Select Item From List"));
                            toolPartPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</br>"));
                            toolPartPanel.Controls.Add(ddlItems);


                            toolPartPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</br>"));
                            toolPartPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</br>"));
                            toolPartPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</br>"));

                            //updatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(toolPartPanel);

                            //Controls.Add(updatePanel);
                            Controls.Add(toolPartPanel);
                            base.CreateChildControls();

                            //if (siteInfoWp.ListName != string.Empty || siteInfoWp.ListName != null)
                            //{
                            //    ddlAllLists.SelectedItem.Text = siteInfoWp.ListName;
                            //    if (siteInfoWp.ItemId != string.Empty || siteInfoWp.ItemId != null)
                            //        ddlItems.SelectedValue = siteInfoWp.ItemId;

                            //}
                            #endregion
                        }
                    }
                //});

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ULS.Log(LogCategory.Projects, ex);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Populating dropdown for date and data field
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        ///
        void ddlAllLists_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                populateItemsDropdown();                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ULS.Log(LogCategory.Projects, ex);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public override void ApplyChanges()
        {
            //base.ApplyChanges();
            try
            {
                //SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                //{
                SiteInfoWebPart webPart = (SiteInfoWebPart)this.ParentToolPane.SelectedWebPart;
                webPart.ListName = ddlAllLists.SelectedItem.Text;
                webPart.ItemId = ddlItems.SelectedValue;
                webPart.ApplyChanges();
                //});
                //base.ApplyChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ULS.Log(LogCategory.Projects, ex);
            }
            //EnsureChildControls();

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Populate data in toolpart child controls
        /// </summary>
        public void populateToolPartControls()
        {
            try
            {
                SiteInfoWebPart wp = (SiteInfoWebPart)this.ParentToolPane.SelectedWebPart;
                //SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                //{
                    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
                    {
                        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                        {
                            #region Populate List Dropdown

                            ddlAllLists.Items.Clear();

                            foreach (SPList list in web.Lists)
                            {
                                ListItem li = new ListItem(list.Title, list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl);

                                if (wp.ListName == list.Title)
                                    li.Selected = true;
                                ddlAllLists.Items.Add(li);
                            }

                            #endregion

                            populateItemsDropdown();                                               

                        }
                    }
                //});

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ULS.Log(LogCategory.Projects, ex);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public void populateItemsDropdown()
        {
            try
            {
                //SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                //{
                    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
                    {
                        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                        {


                            SPList lstItems = web.Lists[ddlAllLists.SelectedItem.Text];

                            ddlItems.Items.Clear();

                            foreach (SPItem item in lstItems.Items)
                            {
                                //Populatelist views Dropdown

                                ddlItems.Items.Add(new ListItem(item["Title"].ToString(), item.ID.ToString()));

                            }
                        }
                    }
                ////});
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ULS.Log(LogCategory.Projects, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about which part of the code is not working and what it should be doing? Any details on the environment (2010/2013, what your webpart does, etc) would help too.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your Reply. When my Dropdownlists in the Toolpart panel are changed, and I want it to be saved to the properties of the Web Part. It doesn't save the properties. This is purely the ToolPart part. It is SharePoint 2010, applied with SP2 and August CU 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have rewritten the hole WebPart... and it seems to be a problem with UserControl...

This is the code I have used:

```
using System;
```

using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using Hein.SPF.Development.WebParts.SiteInfoWebPart;
using ETTU.SPEC.Library.Logging;
using Hein.SPF.Development.WebParts.TestWebPart;

namespace Hein.SPF.Development.Library
{
    class SiteInfoToolPart : Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ToolPart
    {
        #region Controls Declaration

```
    DropDownList ddlAllLists;
    DropDownList ddlItems;
    Panel toolPartPanel;        
    #endregion

     /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    ///
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        try
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {

                        #region Creating instances of Toolpart Controls

                        toolPartPanel = new Panel();
                        toolPartPanel.GroupingText = "List Configuration";

                        ddlAllLists = new DropDownList();
                        ddlAllLists.ID = "ddlAllLists";
                        ddlAllLists.AutoPostBack = true;
                        ddlAllLists.Width = Unit.Pixel(200);
                        ddlAllLists.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddlAllLists_SelectedIndexChanged);

                        ddlItems = new DropDownList();
                        ddlItems.ID = "ddlItems";
                        ddlItems.Width = Unit.Pixel(200);

                        #endregion

                        populateToolPartControls();

                        #region Adding all control to toolpart stack


                        toolPartPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Select List"));
                        toolPartPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</br>"));
                        toolPartPanel.Controls.Add(ddlAllLists);


                        toolPartPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</br>"));
                        toolPartPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Select Item From List"));
                        toolPartPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</br>"));
                        toolPartPanel.Controls.Add(ddlItems);


                        toolPartPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</br>"));
                        toolPartPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</br>"));
                        toolPartPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</br>"));

                        Controls.Add(toolPartPanel);
                        base.CreateChildControls();

                        //if (siteInfoWp.ListName != string.Empty || siteInfoWp.ListName != null)
                        //{
                        //    ddlAllLists.SelectedItem.Text = siteInfoWp.ListName;
                        //    if (siteInfoWp.ItemId != string.Empty || siteInfoWp.ItemId != null)
                        //        ddlItems.SelectedValue = siteInfoWp.ItemId;

                        //}
                        #endregion
                    }
                }
            });

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ULS.Log(LogCategory.Projects, ex);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Populating dropdown for date and data field
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    ///
    void ddlAllLists_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {                
            populateItemsDropdown();                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ULS.Log(LogCategory.Projects, ex);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public override void ApplyChanges()
    {

        try
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                SiteInfoWebPart webPart = (SiteInfoWebPart)this.ParentToolPane.SelectedWebPart;
                webPart.ListName = ddlAllLists.SelectedItem.Text;
                webPart.ItemId = ddlItems.SelectedValue;
            });

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ULS.Log(LogCategory.Projects, ex);
        }

    }       
    /// <summary>
    /// Populate data in toolpart child controls
    /// </summary>
    public void populateToolPartControls()
    {
        try
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        #region Populate List Dropdown

                        ddlAllLists.Items.Clear();

                        foreach (SPList list in web.Lists)
                        {
                            ListItem li = new ListItem(list.Title, list.Title);

                            ddlAllLists.Items.Add(li);
                        }

                        #endregion

                        populateItemsDropdown();

                    }
                }
            });

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ULS.Log(LogCategory.Projects, ex);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public void populateItemsDropdown()
    {
        try
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        SPList lstItems = web.Lists[ddlAllLists.SelectedItem.Text];

                        ddlItems.Items.Clear();

                        foreach (SPItem item in lstItems.Items)
                        {

                            ddlItems.Items.Add(new ListItem(item["Title"].ToString(), item.ID.ToString()));

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ULS.Log(LogCategory.Projects, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

}

using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy;

namespace Hein.SPF.Development.WebParts.TestWebPart
{
    [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public class TestWebPart : Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart
    {
        public string ListName
        {
            get
            {
                return _listName;
            }
            set
            {
                _listName = value;
            }
        }
        string _listName;

```
    public string ItemId
    {
        get
        {
            return _ItemId;
        }
        set
        {
            _ItemId = value;
        }
    }

    string _ItemId;

    public override ToolPart[] GetToolParts()
    {
        ToolPart[] allToolParts = new ToolPart[3];

        try
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {

                WebPartToolPart standardToolParts = new WebPartToolPart();
                CustomPropertyToolPart customToolParts = new CustomPropertyToolPart();
                allToolParts[0] = standardToolParts;
                allToolParts[1] = customToolParts;
                allToolParts[2] = new Hein.SPF.Development.Library.SiteInfoToolPart();
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error!!!");
        }

        return allToolParts;
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();
        HiddenField hiddenWebPartProperties = new HiddenField() { ID = "hiddenWebPartProperties" };
        this.Controls.Add(hiddenWebPartProperties);


    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);

        ////Construct JSON using the WebPart Properties
        string webPartPropertiesJSON = string.Empty;
        webPartPropertiesJSON = "{ 'ListName':'" + this.ListName + "', 'ItemId': '"
                                                  + this.ItemId + "' }";
        ((HiddenField)this.FindControl("hiddenWebPartProperties")).Value = webPartPropertiesJSON;

        CssRegistration.Register("/_layouts/Heineken/Hein.SPF.Development/css/webparts.css");

        Panel viewPanel = new Panel() { ID = "PNL_View" };


        this.Controls.Add(viewPanel);

        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site)
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (ListName == null)
                            return;

                        SPList list = web.Lists[ListName];

                        if (ItemId == null)
                            return;

                        SPItem item = list.GetItemById(Convert.ToInt32(ItemId));
                        if (item != null)
                        {
                            Panel dossierPanel = new Panel();
                            dossierPanel.CssClass = "Dossier";
                            viewPanel.Controls.Add(dossierPanel);

                            Panel panelRow = new Panel();
                            panelRow.CssClass = "Row";
                            dossierPanel.Controls.Add(panelRow);

                            Panel panelRowLabel = new Panel();
                            panelRowLabel.CssClass = "Label";
                            panelRow.Controls.Add(panelRowLabel);

                            Panel panelRowInput = new Panel();
                            panelRowInput.CssClass = "Label Indent";
                            panelRow.Controls.Add(panelRowInput);

                            panelRowLabel.Controls.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label { Text = "Dienst" + ":" });
                            panelRowInput.Controls.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label { Text = item["Dienst"].ToString() });

                            Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

                            dict.Add(0, "Applicatie");
                            dict.Add(1, "Heineken Department");
                            dict.Add(2, "Service Coordinator");
                            dict.Add(3, "Service Level");
                            //dict.Add(4, "Dienst");

                            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                            {
                                Panel row = new Panel();
                                row.CssClass = "Row";
                                dossierPanel.Controls.Add(row);

                                Panel rowLabel = new Panel();
                                rowLabel.CssClass = "Label";
                                row.Controls.Add(rowLabel);

                                Panel rowInput = new Panel();
                                rowInput.CssClass = "Label Indent";
                                row.Controls.Add(rowInput);

                                rowLabel.Controls.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label { Text = dict[i] + ":" });

                                try
                                {
                                    SPField field = item.Fields.GetField(dict[i]);

                                    switch (field.Type)
                                    { 
                                        case SPFieldType.Choice:
                                            rowInput.Controls.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label { Text = ((SPFieldChoice)item[dict[i]]).GetFieldValueAsText(item[dict[i]]) });
                                            break;
                                        case SPFieldType.Text:
                                            rowInput.Controls.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label { Text = item[dict[i]].ToString() });
                                            break;
                                        case SPFieldType.Invalid:
                                            if (field.TypeAsString == "TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti")
                                            {   
                                                string[] splittedString = item[dict[i]].ToString().Split('|');
                                                if(splittedString[0] != String.Empty && splittedString[0] != null)
                                                    rowInput.Controls.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label { Text = splittedString[0] });
                                                else 
                                                    rowInput.Controls.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label { Text = "" });
                                            }
                                            break;
                                        case SPFieldType.User:
                                            string user = item[dict[i]].ToString();
                                            int userId = Convert.ToInt32(user.Substring(0, user.IndexOf(";#")));
                                            SPUser spuser = web.AllUsers.GetByID(userId);
                                            rowInput.Controls.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label {Text = spuser.Name});
                                            break;
                                        case SPFieldType.MultiChoice:
                                            SPFieldMultiChoice spfmc = field as SPFieldMultiChoice;
                                            SPFieldMultiChoiceValue spfmcValue = new SPFieldMultiChoiceValue(item[dict[i]].ToString());
                                            rowInput.Controls.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label {Text = spfmcValue[0]}) ;
                                            break;
                                        default:
                                            rowInput.Controls.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label { Text = item[dict[i]].ToString()});
                                            break;
                                    }

                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                { 

                                }

                            }

                            Panel panelRowButton = new Panel();
                            panelRowButton.CssClass = "Buttons";
                            viewPanel.Controls.Add(panelRowButton);

                            //Button button = new Button { Text = "Edit" };
                            //button.Click += new System.EventHandler(EditButton_Click);
                            //panelRowButton.Controls.Add(button);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        base.Render(writer);

    }
}
```

}